# Check if string is in certain format in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have string as below.

`/customer/v1/123456789/account/`

The id in the url is dynamic.

What I want to check is if I have that string how can I be sure that if first part and second part is matching with below structure. `/customer/v1/<customer_id>/account`

What I have done so far is this. however, I want to check if endpoints is totally matching to the structure or not.

```
endpoint_structure = '/customer/v1/'
endpoint = '/customer/v1/123456789/account/'

if endpoint_structure in endpoint:
    return True
return False
```

Endpoint structure might change as well.
For example: `/customer/v1/<customer_id>/documents/<document_id>/` and there will be again given endpoint and I need to check if given endpoint fits with the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression;

```
import re
return re.match(r'^/customer/v1/\d+/account/$', endpoint)
```

or you can examine the beginning and the end:

```
return endpoint.startswith('/customer/v1/') and endpoint.endswith('/account/')
```

... though this doesn't attempt to verify that the stuff between the beginning and the end is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Can solve this using regular expression

> ^(/customer/v1/)(\d)+(/account/)$

Also if you want to specify the minimum length for customer_id 
  (/customer/v1/<**customer_id**>/account ) then use the following regexp

> ^(/customer/v1/)(\d)**{5,}**(/account/)$

Here expecting the customer_id must have at least 5 digits length

[Check here](https://regex101.com/r/4iUKD9/1)